# Binning across multiple categories

Tags: r

I am trying to create a text-output of backup-durations sorted into 30-minute increment bins for 6 of our backup servers. An example of the input data (called newdata) is as follows:

```
      backup_server   client      duration  
1     bkp01           server_A    60       
2     bkp01           server_A    34       
3     bkp01           server_A    230     
4     bkp02           server_A    14      
5     bkp02           server_C    29   
6     bkp02           server_C    62
```

Now I've been able to bin *everything* together with:

```
br.br <-seq(0,max(newdata$duration),by=30)
cbind(table(cut(newdata$duration,br.br,right=FALSE)))
```

Which provides this kind of output:

```
                    [,1]
[0,30)              3523
[30,60)             1394
[60,90)              230
[90,120)              35
[120,150)             10
[150,180)              0
[180,210)              3
```

What I'd like to see is something like this:

```
[,1]                bkp01      bkp02
[0,30)               523        422
[30,60)              394         30
[60,90)              130         10
[90,120)               5          3
[120,150)              1          2
[150,180)              0         10
[180,210)              2         20
```

The closest I got was using the aggregate function but doesn't really do what I need.

```
> aggregate(newdata$Duration, by=list(newdata$TSM_server),FUN=mean)
  Group.1        x
1 bkp01       31.13307
2 bkp02       16.58491
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I only used the `mean` function as an example of how I was able to display data for each backup server. @Doran is correct that that I'm looking for counts. 

I was able to get @doran's code working but I'm still curious how to get @DWin's. I'll post a response to his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not what you want (and by comparing @joran's solution to mine you should see that there is considerable ambiguity to be resolved regarding what summary measure is desired)....

```
 aggregate(newdata$Duration, 
           by=list(dur.cut=cut(newdata$duration,br.br,right=FALSE) , 
                   server=newdata$TSM_server),
            FUN=mean)
```

Then try this:

```
 tapply( newdata$Duration, 
           INDEX=list(dur.cut=cut(newdata$duration,br.br,right=FALSE) , 
                   server=newdata$TSM_server),
            FUN=mean)
```

Sometimes setting `INDEX= interaction(var1, var2)` produces slightly different and at times more desirable results. ( In testing these I do observe that the column names are different than your example.)

```
 aggregate(newdata$duration, 
            by=list(dur.cut=cut(newdata$duration,br.br,right=FALSE) , 
                    server=newdata$backup_server),
             FUN=mean)
#------------
  dur.cut server    x
1 [30,60)  bkp01 34.0
2 [60,90)  bkp01 60.0
3  [0,30)  bkp02 21.5
4 [60,90)  bkp02 62.0

 tapply( newdata$duration, 
            INDEX=list(dur.cut=cut(newdata$duration,br.br,right=FALSE) , 
                    server=newdata$backup_server),
             FUN=mean)
#-------------
           server
dur.cut     bkp01 bkp02
  [0,30)       NA  21.5
  [30,60)      34    NA
  [60,90)      60  62.0
  [90,120)     NA    NA
  [120,150)    NA    NA
  [150,180)    NA    NA
  [180,210)    NA    NA
```

Comment: When I ran your tapply example, it didn't create a new server for each column, instead it listed them
`dur.cut     server    x
  [0,30)       bkp01  NA
  [30,60)      bkp01  34
  [60,90)      bkp01  60
  [0,30)       bkp02  21.5
  [30,60)      bkp02  NA
  [60,90)      bkp02  62.0
`
After posting this, I'm not sure how to make it display correctly, but essentially I had three columns: dur.cut, server, and the mean whereas I wanted dur.cut, bkp01, bkp02, and then the count of each in the datafield.

Comment: Trying to communicate in comments when the output is a table is an exercise in frustration. You've check-marked an answer already, but if the answer is not what you had in mind, you should edit your question to clarify what summary measure(s) are needed and in what arrangement you want the output.

Comment: I had an issue with using dcast on our server version and after reviewing @DWin's solution, I was able to get what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're looking for counts for each backup server within your time bins. (i.e. I wasn't sure what was up with you attempt using `mean`...)

If that's the case, here's one option using `dcast` from the **reshape2** package:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "      backup_server   client      duration  
1     bkp01           server_A    60       
2     bkp01           server_A    34       
3     bkp01           server_A    230     
4     bkp02           server_A    14      
5     bkp02           server_C    29   
6     bkp02           server_C    62",sep = "",header = TRUE,row.names = 1)

#cut altered slightly to make more sense with your small example data
dat$dur <- cut(dat$duration,seq(0,max(dat$duration)+30,by = 30),right = FALSE)
dcast(dat,dur~backup_server,fun.aggregate = length,value.var = "dur")

        dur bkp01 bkp02
1    [0,30)     0     2
2   [30,60)     1     0
3   [60,90)     1     1
4 [210,240)     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! After loading the reshape2 package I was able to get my desired output.